Rule of thumb for selecting Switching frequency of Brake/Regenerative switch
We are analyzing an old existing motor driver which controls a PMSM motor and looking to improve its performance.
The Mosfets used for the 3 phase H bridge operate at a switching frequency of 20 KHz.
We have a brake chopper MOSFET which connects to a series high power resistor to waste any excess energy built up on the DC bus due to regenerative torque or a due to fast deceleration of the motor.
Is there any thumb rule to know what would the ideal switching frequency of the brake MOSFET.?

There is no rule of thumb that can help. It needs proper design and not generalities.

Speaking purely from a power electronics point-of-view, the selection of switching frequency is a consideration of tradeoffs.

You are constrained on the lower end by what may be acceptable from an audible point-of-view. When operating below ~20kHz, you may run into audible hums from your converter, particularly from the magnetic elements.
Lower switching frequencies necessitate the use of larger energy storage elements like filter inductors and capacitors.
Higher switching frequencies result in higher switching losses in the MOSFETs.

Now going to your application, the question to ask is if the braking action need to be synchronous with the motor driver, or if you can operate at a much slower rate. I imagine you would pick a low enough frequency to still capture the dynamics at whatever frequencies of interest you have. In that case, higher frequency will likely only result in higher losses. Having said that, I'm speculating. Some more details on the braking action and a block diagram/schematic could be useful in better understanding the system.

Could you explain what exactly you mean by 'action need to be synchronous with the motor driver', are you taking about H bridge MOSFET PWM synchronization with the brake mosfet's pwm? In that case at the moment it is asynchronous , as the brake is meant to switch on whenever the DC bus crosses a certain threshold. In the existing design, the brake's switching frequency is just 5 KHz and we noticed that whenever a big braking effort is needed(very high duty cycle), there is a lot of ripple in the motor currents, so much so that sometimes the driver stops with a overcurrent fault.

Yeah, that's what I meant. And ok, so it sounds like the brain is another PWM-driven actuation. So, in that case, the same tradeoffs I listed above apply for your brake circuit too. The observed motor current ripple could possibly be due to current sharing from the source.
